# Why should we set /MT to run executable in another pc

Tags: c++, c

I'm reading about /MT and /MD, but I'm a little confused about it

[HEAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is something I don't completely understand :

> /MT Causes your application to use the multithread, static version of the run-time library. Defines _MT and causes the compiler to place the library name LIBCMT.lib into the .obj file so that the linker will use LIBCMT.lib to resolve external symbols.

what does it mean?

Comment: It means your program is linked statically and hence no DLLs need to be installed on the target pc.

Comment: Thanks, then whats the problem if I set /MD instead?

Comment: You have to distribute the runtime DLLs to the target pc as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you link with `/MD` or `/MDd` your program is going to need the CRT dlls in order to run. typically they are called something like `msvcp100.dll` for the C++ runtime and `msvcr100.dll` for the C runtime. If you are deploying your application using an installer, you can add a package with these to your installer so the dlls are going to be there when someone runs the application. If on the other hand you are going to deploy your application just as a single stand alone exe, your users are going to need a copy of these dlls. The latest versions of these dlls usually come with windows itself (not the debug ones) but if your user is running an older version of windows it may not have the needed dlls.

Linking your application to the static version of the CRT saves this whole headache for the price that the exe is slightly bigger (since it contains the CRT in it)

If you do use `/MT` (Static CRT) you have to make sure that everything else that you statically link with uses `/MT` as well. otherwise you'll end up with an executable where part of the code uses the static CRT and part is still depends on the CRT DLL. Other than defeating the basic purpose not needing the CRT DLL, this can also cause other problems.
To make sure what DLLs your exe depends on you can use the [dependency walker.](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: And for the price that any updates to the CRT, even critical security updates, don't get applied to your application, right? How big that risk is depends on the application.

Comment: The Microsoft CRT has been around for 20 or so years. I'd be surprised if there'll ever be a critical security update for it.